# robot init file included in execution scope

Tags: robotframework

I'm currently in a situation where I need to execute my robot framework tests in a certain order, rather than the standard alphabetical file name order. The __init__ file exists in the same directory as my tests. I've made an argument file and listed the test case files out in the order I need, but now if I add the __init__ to the argument targets, I get the error that it has no test cases in it, and if I leave it out, the specification of files rather than a containing directory seems to stop Robot's search for __init__ files.

I'd rather not have to prepend all my test files with an execution order numbering, so does anyone happen to know how I can get robot to pick up on my Settings and still execute in the order I desire?

Thanks

Comment: Would adding the python tag be appropriate here?

Comment: The tag python is not appropriate because this is pure robotframework related (even the file type is .robot).